# How to start a process during kernel debugging (windbg, virtualbox, win7 freeze)

Tags: debugging, windows-7, windbg, virtualbox, freeze

I have written a little program which should exploit a bug inside a function of win32k.sys. My host os is Win7 x64 my guest system too. The guest runs in VitrualBox. My problem is I don't know how to start the exploit in my guest os because after I start debugging with windbg it freezes completely and I can't do anything. Is it right that it freezes? If yes how can I start a process?

sorry for bad english...

Comment: Perhaps your win32 exploit doesn't exist in win64?

Comment: Win32k.sys is a driver and exists in 32 and 64bit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a batch script to run the exploit and set the script to run when the OS starts.

Either that or just press `g` and then press `enter` in WinDbg. Then you will be able to control the debugee and do whatever you like.